# start() is not starting a thread

Tags: java, multithreading

I have written below sample code to test behavior of threads . But main is not starting thread test1 execution , Please let me know what is the problem with this code

```
class test1 implements Runnable
{

    Thread t ; 

    test1(String Name)
    {
        t = new Thread(Name);
        t.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println("Entered test1 run");
    }

}


public class SampleThread{

    public static void main(String[] args)  {
        Thread r = Thread.currentThread();
        System.out.println(r.getName()+" "+r.getPriority());
        r.setName("MainThread");
        r.setPriority(8);
        test1 t1 = new test1("test1");
        System.out.println("calling threads");
        try
        {
            t1.t.join();
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You never place your Runnable into a Thread, and so its run method never runs. This is basic threading and suggests that you will want to Google and study a tutorial on introductory Java threading.

Answer (score 0):

Changing `t = new Thread(Name);` to `t = new Thread(this, Name);` (in test1) would make your code work.

But still your code it quite confusing. You can make a java thread by sub-classing Thread or implementing Runnable and passing the runnable to a thread, and you seem to trying to do both at the same time (incorrectly).

I suggest you look up a guide on threads like https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_multithreading.htm

Comment: Thanks for the response ,  changing  t = new Thread(this); has worked :)

Comment: An object constructor must never allow its `this` pointer to be seen by another thread.  Doing so allows the other thread to see the object in an inconsistent state.